# C++ with inline assembly, whats wrong?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

First please use easy words, as i'm not really good in english ;)

And now the problem:

I wanted to code a program which can encrypt a text of mine with an easy Caesar algorithm. That means that the alphabetic character becomes a later character in the alphabet, but my program does not begin at the beginning of the alphabet after Z. Now the code:

```
void Entschlüsseln(char Text[50], int Schlüssel)
{
    char Entschlüsselt[sizeof(Text)];
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(Text)-1; x++)
    {
        Entschlüsselt[x] = '\0';
    }
        char Zeichen;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Text)-1; i++)
    {
        if (Text[i] != '\0')
        {
            Zeichen = Text[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < Schlüssel; j++)
            {
                _asm
                {
                        mov al, Zeichen   
                        cmp al, 90
                        jb Großbuchstabe
                        mov al, Zeichen
                        sub al, 32
                        mov Zeichen, al
                    Großbuchstabe:
                        inc Zeichen
                        mov al, Zeichen
                        cmp al, 90
                        ja Anfang_Alphabet
                        jmp Ende
                    Anfang_Alphabet:
                        mov Zeichen, 65
                    Ende:
                }   
            }
            Entschlüsselt[i] = Zeichen;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << Entschlüsselt;
}
```

i hope it's ok and you can help me

Comment: Is that a homework? It seems to me that it would be easier to do without the assembly.

Comment: Dont use special characters like äöüß in your code, this will definitely lead to errors.

Comment: Meta info: There were several edits pending for the question. I tried `Improve` instead of `Approve` to fix an additional typo, but that seems to have lost one intermediate edit. Sorry!

Comment: @half: Not definitely, but maybe. UTF-8 is far less portable than ASCII but far more portable than anything else.

Comment: @sehe i wouldn't say worst use of assembly. I would say, however that in my opinion this would be easier to do with just C++ instead of mixed code

Comment: Easier? the compiler will by definition not be able to optimize the code effectively by putting this in inline assembly. So the single reason to use inline asm is thwarted here

Comment: IIRC, whether characters like `äüöß` are translated to UCNs is entirely implementation defined. But I believe a program using those chars as identifiers may be well formed on a supporting impl.

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier to implement in pure C++, without assembly.

```
Zeichen = tolower(Text[i]);
Zeichen += Schlussel; // Note, the C++ standard does not guarantee that non-ASCII characters such as U-umlaut are allowed in identifiers
if (Zeichen > 'Z') Zeichen -= 26;
Entschlusselt[i] = Zeichen;
```

Comment: O.o thanks i didn't know that i can use the > operator with chars, too. :D

Comment: @Domshooter: Sure, `char` at its base is just a small integer data type (it's not specified whether it is signed or unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you only want to change the character if it is really a letter, so that space and other characters stay. And you are using C++, therefore it is easier to work with a `std::string` instead of a `char[]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

void caesar_encode(std::string &text, int schluessel) {

  for (size_t i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char zeichen = text[i];

    int buchstabe = -1; // -1 == unbekannt, 0 = a, 1 = b, ... 25 = z
    if ('A' <= zeichen && zeichen <= 'Z') {
      buchstabe = zeichen - 'A';
    } else if ('a' <= zeichen && zeichen <= 'z') {
      buchstabe = zeichen - 'a';
    }

    char codiertes_zeichen = zeichen;
    if (buchstabe != -1) {
      int codierter_buchstabe = (buchstabe + schluessel) % 26;
      char alphabet_anfang = zeichen - buchstabe; // 'A' oder 'a'
      codiertes_zeichen = alphabet_anfang + codierter_buchstabe;
    }

    text[i] = codiertes_zeichen;
  }
}

int main() {
  string s("Hallo, Welt");
  caesar_encode(s, 13);
  std::cout << s << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Just try to understand this code, it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the wrong code is this line:

```
cmp al, 90
jb Großbuchstabe
```

Since 90 (which in ASCII is a `Z`) is a Großbuchstabe, you should not subtract 32 from it. Make it:

```
cmp al, 90
jbe Großbuchstabe
```